# Fairly simple differentiation question

Tags: derivatives

Ok so the question is :

If $f(x) = \frac {e^x}  {x^6}$ Find $f'(x)$.

I'm fine finding the answer, I know $\frac {e^x}{x^6} = e^x * \frac {1}{x^6}$ so I went ahead and used the product rule and got the right answer. However, my first instinct was to use the quotient rule, and I did that first and got it wrong.

My question is: why is the quotient rule wrong here, after all it is one function divided by another?

Comment: Quotient rule isn't wrong. You must have made a mistake. Show us your work.

Comment: The quotient rule will give you the correct answer.

Comment: What did you do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably got wrong the sign in the quotient rule. It is: $$\left (\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}.$$

This way:

$$\left(\frac{e^x}{x^6}\right)' = \frac{e^x x^6 - 6e^x x^5}{x^{12}} = \frac{e^x}{x^6} -\frac{6e^x}{x^7}.$$

On the other hand:

$$(e^x x^{-6})' = e^x x^6 + e^x(-6x^{-7}) = \frac{e^x}{x^6} -\frac{6e^x}{x^7}.$$

Ok?

Comment: ah ok thanks very much, I got both of them answers except I didn't see that they were equivalent (i didn't do that extra step in the quotient rule to split them up) Thanks very much

Comment: Glad to help! ${}$

Answer (score 1):

Quotient Rule: $$f'(x)={(e^x)'(x^6)-(e^x)(x^6)'\over (x^6)^2}={e^x(x^6)-e^x(6x^5)\over x^{12}}$$

Product (and Chain) Rule:
$$f(x)=e^xx^{-6}=(e^x)'(x^{-6})+(e^x)(x^{-6})'=(e^x)(x^{-6})+(e^x)(-6x^{-7}).$$

These are algebraically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use $$\left( \frac f g \right)' = \frac {f'g-fg'} {g^2}$$

then you get:
$$\left( \frac {e^x} {x^6} \right)' = \frac {e^x\cdot x^6 - 6\cdot x^5\cdot e^x} {x^{12}}$$